# How much did Lucius Malfoy know about the workings of the diary?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, plot-device

From CoS (or was it from HBP?) we get a very vague hint at how much Lucius knew about the diary; Dumbledore tells Harry that Voldemort probably told Lucius that the diary would help open the Chamber of Secrets, and there was some plan that Voldemort wanted to put into action, which never happened because his power got destroyed when he attacked Harry (sorry I don't remember the exact scene).

Non-the-less I doubt Voldemort told him any details on how the diary worked. He had to keep his horcruxes a top secret, and somehow I don't see him telling Lucius that the diary had his actual memories locked inside of it, and that it had the capability to possess other people. However, from book 2 we know that Lucius knew enough to plant the diary on a student going to Hogwarts, that it would definitely open the Chamber of Secrets, and somehow the student who had the diary planted on would be blamed for it (which was the reason he planted it on Arthur Weasley's daughter). We also know that a lot of the things in book 2 happened due to pure luck. After Ginny threw the diary down Myrtle's toilet, it just happened to have been picked up by Harry. It might have been picked up by anybody, might have been flushed down a different toilet entirely (the reason it was even found by Harry was because Myrtle threw it back out), or it might not have been taken to Hogwarts in the first place (if Ginny's parents had checked her books after returning home from Diagon Alley before giving them to her, they might have realized the diary was not something they bought and might have just kept it at the house, possibly even recognized that it had some dark magic on it).

So I am curious to know, how much about the diary did Lucius know exactly? What was he hoping would happen? Did he think it would just cause chaos, or even cause Voldemort to come back somehow (this I doubt, seeing how scared he was when Voldemort did come back in book 4, and he doesn't seem like the person to be that loyal, to actually want Voldemort to come back)? Is any information available on this topic?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112931/why-did-lucius-give-tom-riddles-diary-to-ginny