# When did Lucius Malfoy come up with the plot of the diary?

Tags: harry-potter

There's an interesting discussion on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/16aiwxo/lucius_malfoy_a_lockhart_fan_girl/):

> When Harry is in Borgin and Burkes Lucius tells Borgin he needs to hurry as he has important business elsewhere. The next thing we know he’s in Flourish and Blotts for Lockhart’s book signing.
> Is Lucius Malfoy a Lockhart fan girl?

To which the top comment replies:

> We know he is trying to get rid of the diary, so its possible he wanted to get to Flourish and Blott's before the Weasleys left.

This discussion got me thinking: When did Lucius come up with this diary plan? Was it premeditated, a deliberate framing of the Weasleys? Or was it on the spur of the moment, when Flourish and Botts perhaps refused to buy it off him, and he decided impulsively to dump it on Ginny?

When did Lucius come up with this plan?

(Not a dupe of [Why did Lucius give Tom Riddle's diary to Ginny?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112931/why-did-lucius-give-tom-riddles-diary-to-ginny) as I am interested in the timing, not the plot.)

Comment: Maybe Lucius wasn't a fan girl, but Molly Weasley definitely was.  If Lucius somehow *knew* this, then that would allow him to guess the time at which the Weasleys would show up to Flourish and Botts - giving him a reason to "hurry".  Not offering as an answer because I don't know of any textual evidence regarding what Lucius knew or didn't know about Molly.

Answer (score -1):

As the answers in [Why did Lucius give Tom Riddle's diary to Ginny?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112931/why-did-lucius-give-tom-riddles-diary-to-ginny) say Malfoy´s plan are to discredit Arthur so that the law that he approves is repealed.

The readers know that the law is approved sometimes before Harry travel to Diagon Alley because Malfoy tells Mr. Borgin that he have to sell some items for this law.

So Malfoy comes with the plan at least before he travels to Knockturn Alley.

Comment: Logic doesn't follow. Could be he planned on selling or destroying the diary, and changed his mind when seeing the Weasleys.

Comment: How he could destroy the diary when Voldemort tell then to protect the diary, also selling don´t make sense for the same reason. As the answers for the questions i cited tell Dumbledore makes an assumption for Malfoy´s plan and Dumbledore ideas are usually correct,